# How to access a variable value in another view in blade template?

Tags: php, laravel

My Views Code in blade template is like this:

Views/Mainview.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @php 
        $baalgh = array();
    @endphp
    @include('tabs.familyview')
    <?php print_r($baalgh); //prints empty array ?>
    @include('tabs.childview') //need $baalgh value inside this view
@endsection
```

Views/tabs/familyview.blade.php

```
@foreach($membersdata as $key=>$onemember)
    @php 
        $age = calculateage($onemember->memberdob);
        $onemember->age = $age;
        ((18 <=> $age) === 1)?:$baalgh[] = $onemember;
    @endphp
@endforeach
<?php print_r($baalgh); //here it displays data ?>
```

my question is how to **access values** of `$baalgh` in *mainview* and *childview* ?

Comment: Please don't do this. If you are using a lot `@php` blocks in your views, you should probably move this logic to your controller.

Comment: this loop in Views/tabs/familyview.blade.php is actually to display data.

Comment: @ImranQamer Can you try my code

Comment: why dont you prepare your data in the controller then send them to the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems a bit unorganized, you should try to keep the calculations inside your controller, and use the views as the presentation of your calculated data. I suppose you can do something like this:

In your controller:

```
$baalgh = $membersdata->filter(function($total, $member){
    $member->age = calculateage($member->memberdob);
    return $member->age <=> 18;
});

return view("Mainview.blade.php", ["baalgh" => $baalgh, "membersdata" => $membersdata]);
```

Then in your `Views/Mainview.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @include('tabs.familyview')
    @include('tabs.childview')
@endsection
```

And on your `Views/tabs/familyview.blade.php`:

```
<?php print_r($baalgh); //here it displays data ?>
```

It is much simpler this way.

Comment: I am using foreach loop to achieve two things, one to display data and second to store age value in another array. but if i follow your logic then i will need to reduce it twice.... it is what m thinking .... m i right?

Comment: The reduce is only to calculate the age in the controller. It's ok to use a foreach loop to display data in your blade view.

Comment: Sorry reduce is not right there you should use map instead to get an array. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow simple steps for include array into child view:

**Views/Mainview.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    @php 
        $baalgh = array();
    @endphp
    @include('tabs.familyview', ['baalgh' => $baalgh])
    {{ var_dump($baalgh) }} //prints empty array

@endsection
```

**Views/tabs/familyview.blade.php**

```
@foreach($membersdata as $key=>$onemember)
    @php 
        $age = calculateage($onemember->memberdob);
        $onemember->age = $age;
        ((18 <=> $age) === 1)?:$baalgh[] = $onemember;
    @endphp
@endforeach
<?php print_r($baalgh);

 @include('tabs.childview', ['baalgh' => $baalgh])
```

**Views/tabs/childview.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($baalgh as $baal)
    {{$baal}} // $baalgh array is updated.
@endforeach
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for replying but problem is you are using $baalgh array in both views my question is a little bit different, i am not only using but assigning values to an empty array from first child view and using same array in second child view... similar to pass by reference.

Comment: @ImranQamer For that scenario, you can include `tabs.childview` in the `tabs.familyview` file. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Nice Suggestion but i need to include childview twice in mainview.